# Powershell - check if csv row has data

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Trying to get this snippet I found to work for me. I need to check a folder and see if there are any files. If so, go through each one and check if at least one row of data exists (excluding the headers). Anyone help me out? Not sure how to read the files and then check the rows. Or any other ways to achieve this?

```
$csvData = Import-Csv "C:\Users\MG\Desktop\ScanFolder"                       
{
foreach($dataRow in $csvdata){
    $result = #dosomething} 
    if($result ){
        Write-Host "Data Exists"
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Empty"
    }
}}
```

Comment: `Get-Content` could help here. How do you know if at least one row of data exists? Do you need to parse the CSV data? Just check that file size is not zero?

Comment: @DanWilson - no, that won't work if the CSV file has headers but no data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `Import-CSV` a CSV file with only the header record, it will succeed, but the result will be an array of length zero. Given your request, you should be able to do something like

```
$csvpath = "C:\CSVFiles"
ForEach ($file in (Get-ChildItem $csvpath)) {
    If ((Import-CSV $file).length -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "$file has no data"
    }
}
```

Comment: tried your suggestion - using my path to the csv file, but it doesn't do anything. As in, it just goes to a new command line.  Have I missed something out?

Comment: That might simply mean that all of your CSVs have at least one line of data in them. Note also that the code above is assuming that all of the files in `$csvpath` are CSV files. What you have in this answer is just a framework showing the approach; you can - and should - add error checking and additional reporting.

Comment: I just have one file and it only has headers. I think I had an error in the code. However, as I am running using admin, I get this path error: Import-CSV : Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\test_1.csv'. How would I specify the path to be C:\Users\MG\Desktop\ScanFolder

Comment: You may need to use `$file.fullpath` instead of `$file` for the `Import-CSV`; I can never remember under what circumstances that's needed.

Comment: Like this: if ((Import-CSV $file.fullpath) ?

Comment: Yes - or actually, it might be `fullname` instead; I'm working from memory and mine is less than perfect. Try `Get-ChildItem $csvpath | Select-Object -first | Get-Member`; that will give you a list of the fields and methods in a file object.

Comment: OK, that error can easily be bypassed; `Get-ChildItem -Path $csvpath` instead of just `Get-ChildItem $csvpath`

Comment: Much appreciate the help! This is my full snippet - can you see anything wrong? 
                                                                                                          
$csvToCheck = "C:\Users\MG\Desktop\ScanFolder"
          
ForEach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $csvToCheck | Select-Object -First | Get-Member)) {
    if ((Import-CSV $file).length -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "$file has no data"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$file has data"
    }
}

Comment: Error: Select-Object : Missing an argument for parameter 'First'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Int32' and try again.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear in some of my earlier comments; for example, the command using `Get-Member` was intended to be separate, to verify for you whether it was `fullname` or `fullpath`, since I couldn't remember which. Glad to hear you got it working! :)